# Create React App produces different chunk file names for same code from different CI jobs

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, dockerfile, create-react-app

We have a CI setup which builds a React app via Dockerfile into an Nginx image.

Now we want to upload source maps for the same commit to Sentry but in a separate job.

I have read [this comment on Github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5526#issuecomment-431861378) already and made sure that the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile is exactly the same absolute path as the job's directory for the Sentry source map upload job.

However, both React builds produce different file names:

```
403.55 KB  build/static/js/2.0bd71bf6.chunk.js
165.73 KB  build/static/js/main.f6fff2fd.chunk.js
37.5 KB    build/static/css/main.031b7dea.chunk.css
784 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.96388d36.js
```

vs.

```
403.59 KB  build/static/js/2.1bf300db.chunk.js
165.78 KB  build/static/js/main.acdd9b95.chunk.js
37.5 KB    build/static/css/main.031b7dea.chunk.css
784 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.96388d36.js
```

I tried to read into the responsible Webpack plugins but it's been quite a difficult journey so far to fully understand what is the exact input for a `contenthash`. I hope anyone has an idea?

Comment: Using different .env variables can cause the issue.

Comment: `contenthash` is responsible for hashing file names base on their content. You might want to double-check if these files are completely the same in the two builds. I can also see that their size are different. `403.55 KB` vs `403.59 KB `

Comment: @Vadzim yeah I know, but this can be ruled out, because we use an Nginx substitution mechanism to replace the `REACT_APP_*` env vars with placeholders.

Comment: @TillKolter are they the same in both CI jobs? As Ryan Le said, hash depends on the content, so if the hashes are different, it means that content is different. Maybe try to diff the files?

Comment: @RyanLe you were right. I downloaded the artifacts from Sentry and copied from the pod beautified it and it turned out that there was a diff, although very very subtile. CRA doesn't behave very well, when a library references unresolved env vars and serializes process.env object in the code. It's a nasty and known issue, but I am aware of it and we have it under control, that nothing is exposed. Even if there was no diff in the set of vars (and their placeholder values), there was a diff between the *order* of two particular env vars in the object.

Comment: After dozens of iteration I realized, that the Gitlab yaml initialized those two variables. The values werent reflected in the rendered output (because being replaced by placeholders). However, somehow the explicit setting of the var must have impacted the exports of the vars in the script and cause the diff. I still can't fully explain what happened, but I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: In my case the `.env` are the same but the difference is between CSS Module `[hash]`, how to make this also common.